# C++: How to write a concept that demands that constructor is noexcept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, noexcept

How do I write a concept that demands that the class has a `noexcept` constructor? For example, the following `static_assert` is true in Clang 15.0.7, although I feel that it shouldn't.

```
class Ragdoll {
    int age_ = -1;
public:
    Ragdoll(int age) /* noexcept */ : age_(age) {}

    int meow() const;
    int lose_hair();
};

template<typename Cat>
concept cat = requires(Cat cat) {
    noexcept(Cat{42});
    { cat.meow() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};

static_assert(cat<Ragdoll>);
```

What is the `noexcept` expression doing then anyway in the concept? (Feel free to also link any good concepts tutorials)

Comment: `noexcept(x)` is an expression evaluating to a `bool` value: either `true` or `false`. Code inside `requires` does not require an expression to return `true`, the code just needs to be valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if an expression is `noexcept` in a requires expression with a `noexcept` before the `->` or `;`:

```cpp
template<typename Cat>
concept cat = requires(const Cat cat) {
    { Cat{42} } noexcept;
    // If you wanted the member function to be noexcept too for example
    { cat.meow() } noexcept -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, apparently the following works (in the sense that it triggers the `static_assert`), although I'd prefer to somehow specify it in the `requires` clause.

```
template<typename Cat>
concept cat = noexcept(Cat{42}) && requires(Cat cat) {
    { cat.meow() } -> std::same_as<int>;
};
```